# UICollectionView _computeGaps wasting huge time

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, core-animation, uicollectionviewlayout

In my UICollectionView with custom layout when i try to insert new cells, the UI become slow.
The Time and allocation instrument show me there is a probel with  _computeGaps.

Each time i scroll, i need to insert new cells and the allocation instrument show me memory increase around +200Mb. It goes down when cells appear but it make my scroll very laggy, a couple of seconds first and it takes always more time on next scroll until the UI freeze completely.

Allocation instrument is full of this line:

```
__NSArrayI ...blabla UIKIT... __38-[UICollectionViewUpdate _computeGaps]_block_invoke171
```

It count in totla 1GB afer 2 minutes but only 24MB persistent. What is he doing ?
I know i refresh multiple section on the same time but i can't do it in small chunck otherwise i hit the 31 simulaneous animation limit on Ipad (more section to display).

Refresh code of my collection:

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
   [self.epgCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
           if ([arrayIndexpathToInsert count] > 0) {
                   [self.epgCollectionView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayIndexpathToInsert];
               }
               if ([arrayIndexpathToReload count] > 0) {
                   [self.epgCollectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:arrayIndexpathToReload];
               }
           } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

           }];
   }];
```

I can paste more code but since i don't know where the problem is, i don't know which part i must show you.

Edit:

If i use:

```
[epgCollectionView reloadData];
```

There is no spike and the scrolling don't hang. Reloading the whole thing should take more time that insert/reload, no ? It's not the case for me.